# Why Called StackOverflowException? Why not HeapOverSizedException?

Tags: c#, exception

Sample Code :

```
Static void main(string[] args) { Class1 c1 = new Class1(); }

Class1 { Class1() { Class2 c2 = new Class2(); } }

Class2 { Class2() { Class1 c1 = new Class1(); } }
```

The above code throws `StackOverFlowException`. Here we are creating `Class1` & `Class2` objects recursively. Objects are stored in Heap, then why it is not throwing `HeapOversizedException` or `someotherException` Related to Heap?

Comment: Because you are not running out of heap (memory), you are blowing the stack with recursion.

Comment: Additionally, there *is* a "heap oversized exception". It's called [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx).

Comment: That will be defined as `OutOfMemoryException` this is Stack which refers to Thread's Execution Stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infinite recursion always causes `StackOverflowException`. This is not because of object allocations but because the call to a method must remember the address of the caller on the stack and doing it infintely overflows the stack.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_recursion#Infinite_recursion) has a quite formal description of that process.

Comment: To add, every time that you call a function (and in this case, the constructor), the stack has to remember where to return to (after the function is called).  It has a limited number of places to store this return information.

Answer (score 3):

> StackOverflowException - stack will be used to store current address
>   and jump to function code to execute. Then it will be released or
>   popped when function returns. Since your call never going to end or return,
>   continuously stack has been filled with  address and got it filled.